# Validate modal-form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem with validate modal-form with jquery. If i click the button nothing happens. Instead if i write inside an input form and i click on the button it convalidate.It's like the code didn't see the javascript. I have locked the solutions of my problem many times but i can't find them. I have a separate file javascript and i put it in the head of the page where is the modal. I put also the links for the jquery library from google.

*I noticed that when i open the page for the first time and press the button to validate it validate without check the parameters that i write in the script and the other times when i click the button nothing happens.*

Here the links of the libraries:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is my modal contain the form:

```
<!-- Modale -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modaleReg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modale" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm" id="modifyMod" role="document">
            <!-- Contenitore modale -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Header modale -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="titMod">modale</h5>
                    <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </div>
                <!-- Body modale -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                        <!--Form per iscrizione -->
                        <form action="#" id="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Nome</label>
                                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="surname">Cognome</label>
                                <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cognome">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
                                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Non condivideremo mai la tua email con nessuno.</small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Crea password</label>
                                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="confermaPsw">Conferma password</label>
                                <input id="confermaPsw" name="confermaPsw" type="password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnmod">Continua</button>
                        </form>
                </div>
                <!-- Footer modale -->  
              <div class="modal-footer">
              </div>
              <!--Fine contenitore modale -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Fine modale -->
```

This is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Selezione form e definizione dei metodi di validazione
$("#form").validate({
    // Definiamo le nostre regole di validazione
    rules : {
        // name - nome del campo di input da validare
        name : {
          // Definiamo il campo name come obbligatorio
          required : true
        },
        password : {
            required : true,
            // Settiamo la lunghezza minima e massima per il campo password
            minlength : 5,
            maxlength : 8
        },
         email : {
            required : true,
            // Definiamo il campo email come un campo di tipo email
            email : true
        }
    },
    // Personalizzimao i mesasggi di errore
    messages: {
        name: "Inserisci il nome",
        password: {
            required: "Inserisci una password password",
            minlength: "La password deve essere lunga minimo 5 caratteri",
            maxlength: "La password deve essere lunga al massimo 8 caratteri"
        },
        email: "Inserisci la tua email"
    },
});
```

});

Comment: Have you checked for any javascript errors on your developer console? If jquery.min.js is included you don't need to include jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js

Comment: Hi Priyank, if i remove jquery-3.3.1 slim.min.js the modal that is opened by a button doesn,t work. I press the button and the page blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add below code with validate function and try again

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Selezione form e definizione dei metodi di validazione
$("#form").validate({
    // Definiamo le nostre regole di validazione
    rules : {
        // name - nome del campo di input da validare
        name : {
          // Definiamo il campo name come obbligatorio
          required : true
        },
        password : {
            required : true,
            // Settiamo la lunghezza minima e massima per il campo password
            minlength : 5,
            maxlength : 8
        },
         email : {
            required : true,
            // Definiamo il campo email come un campo di tipo email
            email : true
        }
    },
    // Personalizzimao i mesasggi di errore
    messages: {
        name: "Inserisci il nome",
        password: {
            required: "Inserisci una password password",
            minlength: "La password deve essere lunga minimo 5 caratteri",
            maxlength: "La password deve essere lunga al massimo 8 caratteri"
        },
        email: "Inserisci la tua email"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      // code to submit the form
    }
});
});
```

You can also try to add you code in modal box and it will works fine

Comment: Hi Manoj, thanks for answering the question. I have tried to put the script code below the modal and inside but it doesn't work yet.